# how to keep track of image which should not goes out of the container

Tags: android

Issue:
 when image is drag or move is goes out of the view that i don't want
     i want view contain that image after move image can not drag or move
     image should be present in the layout

i follow this link : https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/MultitouchWithDynamicAddandRemove
[image]

here one image is contain LinearLayout

[image]

and that image we can see here goes some part of the screen that i dnt want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Image/Download_Free_code_Image_Multitouch.htm

using this example i have solve my problem